# map.fitbounds google maps api v3 not working for location selected from jQM panel

Tags: jquery, google-maps, jquery-mobile, google-maps-api-3

On loading the homepage I am using `map.fitbounds` to fit in a few locations on the map. This is working fine. But when I choose a location **manually** from the `panel in the header` the supposed two locations (origin and destination) don't fit on the map and are out of focus. After I **zoom out** then I can see those locations and they appear to be **within** the bounding polyline.

Note: this is the second time the map is loaded. The first time the map is loaded automatically and is working fine.

**This is the code to load the map manually on click.**

```
$('#mylist').children().each(function(){
var anchor = $(this).find('a');
  if(anchor.attr('id') != null){
     anchor.click(function(){
    $("#mypanel").panel("close");
    var panelStation = [];
        panelStation.push({"name": anchor.attr('id'), "localurl": $(this).data('localurl'),"latitude": $(this).data('latitude'), "longitude": $(this).data('longitude'),"distance": $(this).data('distance'), "duration": $(this).data('duration')});
        var latlngbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        latlngbounds.extend(new google.maps.LatLng(panelStation[0].latitude, panelStation[0].longitude));
        latlngbounds.extend(origin);
        var mapOptions = {mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP};
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);
        var markerOrigin = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: origin,
            map: map,               
            title: "Origin!"
        });

        var markerDestination = new google.maps.Marker({
           position: new google.maps.LatLng(panelStation[0].latitude, panelStation[0].longitude),
           map: map,                
           title: "Destination!"
        });
        map.fitBounds(latlngbounds);
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function() {
          var bounds =  map.getBounds();
          var ne = bounds.getNorthEast();
          var sw = bounds.getSouthWest();

          var boundingBoxPoints = [
            ne, new google.maps.LatLng(ne.lat(), sw.lng()),
            sw, new google.maps.LatLng(sw.lat(), ne.lng()), ne
          ];
          var boundingBox = new google.maps.Polyline({
            path: boundingBoxPoints,
            strokeColor: '#FF0000',
            strokeOpacity: 1.0,
            strokeWeight: 2
          });

          boundingBox.setMap(map);
        });                         
     });
  }
});
```

After I zoom out it looks like this and notice the locations **within the bounds**.
[image]
However they are out of focus in the beginning. You can also check it online:
[here](http://crossplatform.co.nf/)

I wonder whether it has to do with the `fitbounds` used to display the map on the `pageinit` in the beginning. But again, I am redrawing the map all over again on the second attempt after manually selecting a location which should have been fine. I cannot quite figure out what is causing this trouble.

**Update 1:**
This is most probably due to the css of the `#map-canvas`, because as I remove few items from the the list panel `#mypanel`, it works fine.

**CSS:**

```
html { height: 100% }
body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
#map-canvas, #map-page { height: 100% }
#map-canvas {
padding: 0;
position : absolute !important; 
top : 40px !important;  
right : 0; 
bottom : 40px !important;  
left : 0 !important;     
}
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BcNVu/1/). But the map is not displayed there despite adding the resources.

**Update 2:**

It turns out that the list panel `#mypanel` when gets populated, its height is causing the trouble. For few items in the list it works fine but when the items are more, it seems that the viewport also gets elongated with it. The panel `div` is:

```
<div data-role="panel" id="mypanel" data-theme="a">
</div>
```

I am using the default jQM css which wraps the panel content in a div with class `ui-panel-inner`. So if I **override** its height like `#mypanel .ui-panel-inner{height: 40px !important;}`, it solves the problem.

But I don't thinks it's an elegant solution and rather a hack. Or rather is it **the way**? I'd like to hear some better approach.

Comment: Please provide instructions on how to reproduce the problem. If I go to your live version, I only see one location.

Comment: Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/BcNVu/

Comment: Please let us know when it works and exhibits the problem.

Comment: I have added all the external resources in the fiddle. But the map is not loading.

Comment: @geocodezip: The only location you see, is it on the homepage when it is loaded? Or is it when you choose a location from the panel? If it is the latter, that is the problem I was talking. When you choose a location from the panel, you should supposedly see the two locations.

Comment: If I deny geolocation, it doesn't work at all in Firefox.  What panel?  I don't ever see any locations to choose from any panel.

Comment: The geolocation access should be granted, otherwise you cannot see anything.

Comment: Just a note related to the fiddles: you have to choose "no wrap(in head)" instead of "onload" at the "Frameworks & Extensions"-section : http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/BcNVu/12/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the fiddle to work now and surprisingly the code there works fine without any modification. http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/BcNVu/12/. I had the `panel div` like this:

```
<div data-role="panel" id="mypanel" data-theme="a">
</div>
```

Unlike in the fiddle, at least in my development environment, I had to add

```
#mypanel .ui-panel-inner{height: 40px !important;}
```

to the css to make it work.. Because the default `jQM css` wraps the `panel content` in a div with class `ui-panel-inner`. So if I **override** its height, it solved the problem. Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/BcNVu/14/.